# IOS absolute URL change event

Tags: ios, url, events, absolute

My file saved in this path. I have uploaded the app to the AppStore, and sometimes some users could not access this file. Because `"4EF53465-E87C-49E4-BE1E-8F273F358D8C"` changes.

`file:///Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6BF0B7C0-AE59-42A8-ACAC-2A58D01A6737/data/Containers/Data/Application/4EF53465-E87C-49E4-BE1E-8F273F358D8C/Documents/`

Help me please to understand how to reproduce the change event.

Comment: Show how you are reading the path

Comment: I am using this 
`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]`

Comment: @CZ54 is it possible to have a change in the sandbox path during usage time?
Because the user has a different path without AppStore update.

Comment: I would say `yes`, you must alway re-calculate the path. Never store the "initial" value

Comment: haw to re-calculate? Can you send an example, please